# java.io.NotSerializableException: org.omnifaces.taghandler.Converter - Not using MyFaces in project

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, omnifaces

We are using

- JSF 2.2
- Primefaces 6.1
- Weblogic 12.2.1

Getting the below exception when trying to use omnifaces.ListConverter for primefaces autocomplete component (in a datatable on row edit). Searched the forum and found BalusC's solution about [MyFaces bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604312/java-io-notserializableexception-org-omnifaces-taghandler-converter?answertab=votes#tab-top), but that doesn't seem to be the issue here as MyFaces is not used in our project. Please help! Thanks.

xhtml Code:

```
  <p:autoComplete id="acsItemNumList" value="#{auditBean.selectedItem.acsItemNumberPrompt}" completeMethod="#{auditBean.completeAudit}" dropdown="true" style="min-width:50%" 
                                                  required="#{aud.acsItemNumberMand eq 'Y'}"  var="rec" itemLabel="#{rec.acsItemNumberPrompt}"  itemValue="#{rec.acsItemNumberPrompt}">
                                          <o:converter converterId="omnifaces.ListConverter" list="#{auditBean.itemLOV}"/>
                                      <f:ajax event="change" render="acsItemDesc acsLotNumList" listener="#{auditBean.onItemNumLOVSelected}"/>

                                  </p:autoComplete>
```

Bean:

```
    public List<AccountabilityAuditEntity> completeAudit(String query){
    List<AccountabilityAuditEntity> results = new ArrayList<AccountabilityAuditEntity>();
    if(itemLOV!=null){
        for(AccountabilityAuditEntity audit:itemLOV){
            if(audit.getAcsItemNumberPrompt().contains(query)){
                results.add(audit);
            }
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

Exception:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.omnifaces.taghandler.Converter
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1378)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1174)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.doWriteState(ClientSideStateHelper.java:425)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.writeState(ClientSideStateHelper.java:210)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.writeState(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:126)
at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.writeState(StateManagerImpl.java:113)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.getState(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:329)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:221)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:475)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
at org.omnifaces.viewhandler.OmniViewHandler.renderView(OmniViewHandler.java:115)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:651)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at weblogic.websocket.tyrus.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:274)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:141)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:650)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:124)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:232)
at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:94)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:248)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3683)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3649)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2433)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2281)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2259)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1686)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1646)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
```

Comment: To exclude one and other, are you anywhere using `binding` attribute tied to a view or session scoped managed bean?

Comment: @BalusC - Thanks for your response. "binding" attribute is not used anywhere in the project. Btw, due to timelines, I replaced autocomplete with editable selectonemenu and got around this problem.

Comment: And a **big thank you** for your work on Omnifaces and detailed answers in SO..I am a newbie in JSF and these helped a lot.